# Entity Framework Core include loading extra navigational properties

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.1

I am using .NET Core and EF Core 2.1.

I am using a very simple type query:

```
var entities = context.SomeEntity
                      .Include(s => s.AnotherEntity)
                      .ToList();
```

This works fine, but if `AnotherEntity` has navigational properties, it loads those automatically. This is becoming a problem with very large applications because some of my web api calls are returning large amounts of data because the of all the nested entities.

Is this a model design problem or setting I can't find? I have not enabled lazy loading.

**EDIT**

Turns out the problem was there were multiple other context calls within the same webapi action.  If a navigation property existed on one of the other calls, it would load all navigation properties.  I fixed it by adding .AsNoTracking().

Comment: if this is legit, you should probably report this issue in Github - .net core repository- https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) documentation about lazy-loading.

Maybe you can solve your problem by using the [proxies Nuget pacckage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/)

Also, remember that navigation properties in your classes must be virtual.

Comment: I am not sure I want to use lazy-loading.  I would like to be able to just use ThenInclude() to load any wanted nested relations, instead of them automatically loading.